# Which is better store photo as byte array or store photo as bitmap in object

Tags: android, bitmap, android-image

I want to store photo in object , which is better ?

1. Store it as byte array
2. Store it as bitmap

I am cuurently using byte array

Answer (score 2):

In OO it is generally better to have your classes as close approximate the reality as possible. 
Bitmap closer approximates the reality of a photo than a byte array does.
So Bitmap is better.

Unless Bitmap does not capture essential characteristics of what you call a photo. Say, you only need to store your byte array somewhere. Then Bitmap will be of no use, only complicating the picture. But then it's not a photo.

Answer (score 1):

If you aimed to store image only (remember ,store a  byte array its not showing the image anyway  )then storing image in  byte array is good  ,

but when it comes to  show the image in some view you have to convert those  byte array in bitmap which may occupied memory  more then you direct store image in bitmap .

so over all bitmap is more convenient option , but again its totally up to your requirement